# Postgresql - upsert big table is very slow

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I have simple table **id_exp** with 130M records, PostgreSQL 11.

ID format - '0123456789', 10 digit.

> **postgresql.conf** (Total RAM 4Gb)
>   shared_buffers = 512MB
>   temp_buffers = 128MB
>   work_mem = 16MB

```
 CREATE TABLE id_exp (
    sn bigint NOT NULL,
    dt date NOT NULL,
    lupdate date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT passid_exp_pkey PRIMARY KEY (sn)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (sn) WITH ( OIDS = FALSE ) TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE TABLE public.id_exp_00 PARTITION OF public.id_exp FOR VALUES FROM ('0') TO ('499999999');
CREATE TABLE public.id_exp_05 PARTITION OF public.id_exp FOR VALUES FROM ('500000000') TO ('999999999');
.....
CREATE TABLE public.id_exp_95 PARTITION OF public.id_exp FOR VALUES FROM ('9500000000') TO ('9999999999');
```

```
select count(*) from only id_exp;
```

count = 0

```
select count(*) from id_exp;
```

count = 128725653

Select query is very fast:

```
select * from passid_exp where sn=3;
```

Total query runtime 125msec.

But UPSERT is slooooowly.

My code (psql -f upd.sql) :

```
START TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_tbl (sn bigint) ON COMMIT DROP;

\COPY tmp_tbl FROM tmp_fms.csv With CSV;

ALTER TABLE tmp_tbl ADD CONSTRAINT tmp_tbl_idx PRIMARY KEY (sn);

DO $$
DECLARE
 tbl integer;
BEGIN

FOR tbl IN SELECT i FROM generate_series(00, 95, 5) AS t(i)
LOOP
  EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO passid_exp_%s (sn,dt,lupdate) (SELECT sn, current_date dt, current_date lupdate from tmp_tbl where sn >= %s00000000 and sn <= %s99999999) ON conflict (sn) DO update set lupdate=current_date', lpad(tbl::text,2,'0'),lpad(tbl::text,2,'0'),lpad((tbl+4)::text,2,'0'));
END LOOP;
END; $$;

COMMIT;
```

Worked 30 minutes!!! Only 500k records.

```
16.12 20:01:08 Start processing
START TRANSACTION
CREATE TABLE
COPY 500000
ALTER TABLE
DO
INSERT 0 0
COMMIT
16.12 20:33:29 End processing
```

Any ideas?

Comment: At a minimum, it would be good to set \timing on to see which of those statements was taking a long time.  Even better would be to run EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) INSERT... to show the plan for the insert.

Comment: Is the column `sn` properly indexed?